# Puppet duplicate declaration: Class[Mongodb] is already declared; cannot redeclare

Tags: puppet, vagrant

Possibly doing something extremely stupid here but I can't find any documentation on what could be causing this.

Setting up a Vagrant VM using Puppet and I'm trying to override a specific setting within the [mongodb](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb) module.

As far as I'm aware the README.md syntax is incorrect in that repo (Although I have tried that too).

My Manifest:

```
include mongodb

class { 'mongodb' :
port => '1111';
}
```

When running `vagrant up` I get the following Error:

```
Duplicate declaration: Class[Mongodb] is already declared; cannot redeclare at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/mongodb.pp:5 on node www
```

If I remove the configuration override it works perfectly but there's no reason why it doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using two notations to achieve the same, but you can only use parameters with the second notation. In short, you are declaring it twice.

So, just lose 'include mongodb' and you're good.

More info: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_classes.html#declaring-a-class-with-include

Comment: Thanks!! Worst part about it is I had that page open when I wrote this question. That'll teach me to do this stuff at 1 in the morning. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just simply remove `include mongodb` line. That will work, but make sure `class { 'mongodb': ... }` will still remain. Otherwise, use `include mongodb`